# Can the Training MSE ever be lower than the variance of the irreducible error?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, dataset, mse

I know that test MSE can't be. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. With enough estimated parameters, training error can always be driven to **zero**.

```
x <- runif(10)
y <- x - x**2 + rnorm(10, sd=1)
M <- lm(y ~ poly(x, degree=9))
```

Here the variance of the irreducible error is $1$.

```
sum((y - predict(M))**2)
```

Gives zero (essentially)

```
[1] 2.889376e-31
```